# На localhost socket.io загружаеться, а на живом сервере не загружаеться

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

Когда проект развёртан на localhost, и с запущеным скриптом node.js и редисом, то всё работает. А когда выложено на живой сервер. То в консоли браузера выбивает такую ошибку.

WebSocket connection to 'wss://178.20.156.148:8892/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Socket.io подключаю так:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Что нужно исправить или где-что нужно настроить, чтобы всё работало?

Код client.js

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:8892/', {
        transports: ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'polling'],
    });

    socket.on('connect', function (user) {
        console.log('Client connected...');
    });

    socket.on('dough', function (data) {
        //Здесь идет добавление данных
    });
});
```

Код server.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server,  {transports: ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'polling'],});
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(8892, function(){
    console.log("listening on *:8892");
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("new client connected");

    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    redisClient.subscribe('dough');

    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        console.log("New message: " + message + ". In channel: " + channel);
        socket.emit(channel, message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });

});
```

---

И ОС на живом сервере - Centos 7

Comment: Зачем в ответ пишешь уточнение к вопросу?

Comment: а порт на сервере открыт?

Comment: @МаксимК, такое бывает если акк не тот, т.е. зайти на сайт под другим провайдером. Мы уже запустили процедуру объединения учётных записей)

Comment: да, порт открытый на сервере